# Is there such a thing as a Negative Poisson Binomial?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The Poisson Binomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial for non-equiprobable Bernoulli trials.

The negative Binomial give the number of Bernoulli trials until a number of success is reached. This is of course for equiprobable trials.

Is there a generalization of the Negative Binomial for non-equiprobable Bernoulli trials?